# Styling custom html code changed the entire page

Tags: html

I am trying to add a countdown to my website as a custom html content but when I add the code it changed the style of the entire page instead of just the counter. PLEASE help me understand what I am doing wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color:#0011;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 10, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What part of this is supposed to only be changing the counter?

Comment: I was expecting style to only work on the counter

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are styling a tag in your header.  When you do this:

```
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color:#0011;
}
</style>
```

What you're telling the HTML is to style any paragraph tag with this styling.  What you'll want to do is delete the code above and modify your innerHTML to use a span or something with a class attribute. Then use a class or an id to style your body.

```
<style>
.test {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color:#0011;
}
</style>

 // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span class='test'>"+days + "d " + hours + "h "
 + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s </span>";
```